# .htaccess in root folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using Nette framework and i have some problems with root folder in my hosting.

My hosting structure:

```
root
    - demo
        - www
           - index.php
    - www
```

and by default I must use this URL address "www.demo.example.com/www" to access to file index.php. But, I don't want to access to web site with "www" postfix. Soooo i create this .htaccess file in root folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ /www/ [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1
</IfModule>
```

and in demo/www folder I'm using this .htaccess

```
    # Apache configuration file (see httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/quickreference.html)

# disable directory listing
Options -Indexes

# enable cool URL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # prevents files starting with dot to be viewed by browser
    RewriteRule /\.|^\. - [F]

    # front controller
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule !\.(pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|rar|zip|tar\.gz)$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# enable gzip compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript text/javascript application/javascript application/json
</IfModule>

# allow combined JavaScript & CSS. Inside of script.combined.js you could use <!--#include file="script.js" -->
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.combined\.(js|css)$">
        Options +Includes
        SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

BUT in this way i can access to web site with "www.demo.example.com" and also with "www.demo.example.com/www", but i don't want access with prefix "www", how can i do it?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a file like this -

```
deny from all
```

> This will prevent any direct acces

---

**UPDATE**

You need only one .htaccess in the root directory like this I think -

```
<Files subdirectory/*>
    deny from all
</Files>
```

> Remove the .htaccess from your subdirectory

Comment: Of course I try this way first, but I can access any way now - Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /www/ on this server. I want access but just from root folder not from www

Comment: I can redirect from PHP if URL address contains "www", but I think it's not the right way. I want to try from .htaccess file

Comment: As far as I am aware ,Files directive matches files by their name and extensions only not directories.

Comment: ohkay @starkeen I'm not much of an expert myself, can you please post a solution and if possible provide a little description of the bare minimum basics?

Comment: of course this is NOT working, how this can work :D I must have the 1. htaccess in root folder because when i don't have it then i can not access from root and also can not from root/www 

I want access from root but do not access from www (but all files are in WWW folder) and thats the problem

Comment: first think what I can do is redirect to root when current addr contains "www" but.. I don't know thats bull*hit :D so I want to know if there are some htaccess solution

Comment: @starkeen still waiting for your answer! :)